# WSO2 WSF/PHP test service

Tags: php, apache, wso2, apache-axis, rampart

After installing WSO2 WSF 2.1.0 on ubuntu 15.04 I'm trying to run the hello service example provided in the documentation (http://wso2.com/project/wsf/php/2.0.0/docs/samples/hello_service.html), but I get:

```
Fatal error: WSService::__construct(): error creating service
```

Looking in /var/log/wsf/wsf_php_server.log I saw this error:

```
[error] dep_engine.c(328) Axis2 Configuration file name not found
[error] conf_init.c(100) Creating deployment engine failed for repository /root/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/wsf_c
```

so I installed libapache2-mod-axis2c, but then reloading apache2 wsf.so isn't loaded anymore and in apache's logs there's this error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/wsf.so' - 
/usr/lib/php5/20131226/wsf_c/lib/librampart.so.0: undefined symbol: axiom_util_clone_node in Unknown on line 0
```

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: This project is no longer supported and maintained by the community

Comment: Yes, I know, but it's still the only resource available atm to send soap attachments with MTOM, so maybe someone can help to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rampart is looking for a missing symbol in libaxis2_axiom.so... In other words you compiled a version of rampart/c looking for missing function(s) in Axis2/c.

You can easily patch your axis2/c by adding the missing functions

Look at this link : https://github.com/gillesgagniard/wso2-wsf-cpp-gg/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=axiom_util_clone_node